# type object 'ArticleSitemap' has no attribute 'filter' Sitemap

Tags: python, django, seo, backend

I am working with the Django sitemap framework. Trying to improve SEO stuff for my blog, I have expanded my Article model in models.py and introduced sitemaps.py in one of the Django apps named MArticles. But I have faced an Attribute Error: type object 'ArticleSitemap' has no attribute 'filter'. Below are my python files.

In **sitemaps.py**

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from .models import Article

class ArticleSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.8

    def items(self):
        return Article.modelmanager.all()

    def lastmodified(self, obj):
        return obj.last_updated
```

In **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from EHub.models import *

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class IpModel(models.Model):
    ip=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ip)
    
class Article(models.Model):
    options=(
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('published','Published'),
    )
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('MArticles:article_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.id,'slug':self.slug})    
    
    class CustomManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status ='published')   
         
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumnails/%y",null=True,blank=True)
    
    description = RichTextUploadingField(null=True,blank=True,   config_name='sourcecode',)
    
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    slug=models.SlugField(null=True,unique=True) 
    tags=TaggableManager()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category,blank=True)
    publish_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)  
    last_updated=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    views=models.ManyToManyField(IpModel,related_name="post_views",blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=options,default='draft')  
    previous_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    next_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)    
    objects = models.Manager()
    modelmanager = CustomManager() 
 
    class Meta:
            db_table = 'article'      
            ordering = ('publish_date',)
            verbose_name ='Article'  
    #name of the models. If there is only one object for this article ,Article will be displayed
            verbose_name_plural = 'Articles'             
    #Otherwise,Articles will be displayed for multiple objects.

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
    
    def totalviews(self):
        return self.views.count()
    
class AComment(MPTTModel):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='Commentor',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    content = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}: {self.content}'
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('publish',)
```

In **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import*

from django.contrib.sitemaps import GenericSitemap # new
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap # new
from MArticles.sitemaps import ArticleSitemap# new

info_dict = {
    'queryset': ArticleSitemap,
}
app_name='MArticles'

urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, 
        {'sitemaps': {'blog': GenericSitemap(info_dict, priority=0.6)}},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'), # new     
      path('articles/',article,name="articles"),
      path('article_detail/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/',article_detail,name="article_detail"),
      path('articles/tag/<slug:slug>/', articletags, name="article-tags"),
 
]
```

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback?

Comment: Well, I have changed the code. It seems sitemap has got some problem with queryset returning.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long.   Please [edit] your post to pare your code down to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)